# Which publication information should be mentioned in CV : Online first, or volume(issue)?

Tags: publications, cv, online-publication, bibliometrics

One of my research work was published in the year 2015 as **Online First** article and has also received a few citations.

Just recently, it got published in the formal **Volume (Issue), pp. 1234 -- 1250, 2017**.

I had listed this publication as ***2015, (In press)*** till now. But, I am now confused, whether should I remove the year 2015 completely from my CV, or should I keep both like **(Online first, 2015), Volume (Issue), pp. 1234 -- 1250, 2017** ?

Comment: What year does the journal use for the volume? Use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really up to you how you list your references, what I do is to list it with the updated information on the CV, due to:

- This reflects the actual state of the article which will come up in searches.
- The later date of the full publication shows that the article is one of the 'latest' in the field.
- The article often has the published online date anyway, alongside the other important dates, at the beginning of the article.

I have always taken the CV as being a way of 'showcasing' the latest state of the researcher's work.